# AWSS3Provider uploading error: Missing required key 'Bucket' in params?

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

I'm using `react-native-image-picker` to get a file path of a video on my iOS simulator phone for my react native app. How do i use this to upload to S3 using Amplify?

```
import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker';
import RNFetchBlob from 'react-native-fetch-blob';
import {Storage} from 'aws-amplify';

class App extends Component {

 constructor(props) {
    super(props)

 }

  //This function is called on a Button click
  pickVideo = async () => {

     const options = {
     mediaType: 'video'
  };

  ImagePicker.launchImageLibrary(options, (response) => {

    if(response.didCancel){
      console.log('User cancelled image picker');
    }
    else if (response.error){
       console.log('ImagePicker error: ', response.error);
    }
    else{
       this.setState({ 
          vidFileName: response.fileName,
        });

        console.log(response.uri);

       this.putFileInS3(response.path, repsonse.filename);
    }
   });

  }

  readFile = (somefilePath) => {
      return RNFetchBlob.fs.readFile(somefilePath, 'base64').then(data => new 
      Buffer(data, 'base64'));
  } 

  putFileInS3 = (filePath, fileName) => {  

    this.readFile(filePath).then(buffer => {
    Storage.put(fileName, buffer, { contentType: 'video/mp4' })
     .then(() => {console.log('successfully saved to bucket');})
     .catch(e => { console.log(e);});
   }
  }
```

Although i get the responses from the image picker, when trying to upload it says AWSS3Provider: Missing required key 'Bucket' in params, even though the user is logged in as an IAM user, using withAuthenticator.

Answer (score 3):

You need to configure your bucket.
https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/storage

Some examples from the above link:
1 -

```
Storage.configure({
    AWSS3: {
        bucket: '',//Your bucket ARN;
        region: ''//Specify the region your bucket was created in;
    }
});
```

2 -

```
import Amplify from 'aws-amplify';

Amplify.configure({
    Auth: {
        identityPoolId: 'XX-XXXX-X:XXXXXXXX-XXXX-1234-abcd-1234567890ab', 
        region: 'XX-XXXX-X', // REQUIRED - Amazon Cognito Region
        userPoolId: 'XX-XXXX-X_abcd1234', //OPTIONAL - Amazon Cognito User Pool ID
        userPoolWebClientId: 'XX-XXXX-X_abcd1234', 
    },
    Storage: {
        AWSS3: {
            bucket: '', //REQUIRED -  Amazon S3 bucket
            region: 'XX-XXXX-X', //OPTIONAL -  Amazon service region
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Fabio, where do these get included (e.g. App.js or another file)? I just worry about making sure it's secure.

Comment: I was pretty certain that i setup with the CLI automatically, so perhaps not needing the manual configuration above. What should my 'aws-exports.js' look like?